# Attempting to effect database columns depending on form checkboxes that are checked

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have a small survey in a HTML form which is submitted to a Java servlet using AJAX.
The user submits information about their gender, age, and which of 8 genres of computer game they like (at least one) and the datetime of form submission.

Here is the MySql table:
[image]

This is the MySQL query:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO vote (sex, age, genre1, genre2, genre3, genre4, genre5, genre6, genre7, genre8, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
```

Here are the genre HTML input fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="1"><label for="1">First Person Shooter</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="2"><label for="2">Sports</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="3"><label for="3">Action/Adventure</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="4"><label for="4">Educational</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="5"><label for="5">Puzzle</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="6"><label for="6">Real Time Strategy</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="7"><label for="7">Beat em up</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre" value="8"><label for="8">Survival Horror</label><br>
```

In the servlet I am trying to check which of the checkboxes have been checked and match them against their corresponding database column, setting the value of that column to one if it matches the checkbox value?!

I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach, but here is my attempt which gives me an SQLException:
`java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3`.

This is my attempt:

```
String[] checkboxes = request.getParameterValues("genre");
int sex = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sex"));
int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));

try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()){

        String query = "INSERT INTO vote (sex, age, genre1, genre2, genre3, genre4, genre5, genre6, genre7, genre8, date) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setInt(1, sex);
        ps.setInt(2, age);

        int column = 3;
        for(int x = 1; x < checkboxes.length; x++){
            if(x == Integer.parseInt(checkboxes[x])){
                ps.setInt(column, 1);
                column++;
            }else{
                ps.setInt(column, 0);
                column++;
            }

        }


        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        out.print("yes");
    }catch(SQLException e){

        out.print(e);
    }
```

So in my query "if checkbox 1 has been checked then set column 3 to 1, if checkbox 2 has been checked then set column 4 to 1". etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Get ParameterValues` will only return the checkbox values that are checked:

```
String[] checkboxes = request.getParameterValues("genre");
```

So your for loop condition `checkboxes.length` would fail. Because you have 10 parameters in your query, and if the user only select 3 check box, then your `checkboxes.length` will be 3. Thus, your code will not set values for the rest of the params.

Better solution would be to create `genre` table and an association table called `voteGenre`. Then use composite key of `voteId` and `genreId`. Every Time someone votes, you insert them into voteGenre table.